# Global extremes of $f(x,y) = \sin(xy)$ in $A$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Find the extremes of $f(x,y) = \sin(xy)$ restricted to points of $A = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2 = 1\}$.

My first attempt was to use Lagrange multipliers, since the procedure of parametrizing the ellipse defined by $x^2+2y^2-1 = 0$ and composing it with $f$ seemed like a dead end.

Deriving $f$ I get that:

- $fx = y \cos(xy)$
- $fy = x \cos(xy)$

Naming $g(x,y) = x^2+2y^2-1$:

- $gx = 2x$
- $gy = 4x$

Then:
\begin{cases}
y \cos(xy) = \lambda 2x\\
x \cos(xy) = \lambda 4y \\
x^2+2y^2-1 = 0
\end{cases} for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

But I can't find solutions to that system, the terms get way too complicated.

Is there any other way I can start to find the extremes? A change of variables at some point perhaps? Or that system should yield solutions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply first equation by $x$, second by $y$ and add first and second side by side you get:

$$2xy\cos(xy)=\lambda(2x^2+4y^2)$$

Next by third equation $\lambda(2x^2+4y^2)=2\lambda$, so:

$$2xy\cos(xy)=2\lambda$$

Now there are two cases $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda\neq 0$. For $\lambda \neq 0$ by first equation:

$$y\cos(xy)=x^2y\cos(xy)$$

Dividing both sides by $y \cos(xy)$ you get:

$$1=x^2$$

The same way you get that $2y^2=1$.Can you finish this solution (case $\lambda=0$ is standard)?

Comment: I like your solution, but couldn't dividing by $y cos(xy)$ generate more conflict cases?

Comment: When $\lambda \neq 0$ then $y\cos(xy) \neq 0$, because $xy\cos(xy)=\lambda$.

Comment: Right. Thanks a lot, agha!

Answer (score 0):

for $x$ and $y$ not equal to zero we obtain $\cos(xy)=\frac{2\lambda x}{y}$ and $\cos(xy)=\frac{2 \lambda y}{x}$ thus we get
$\frac{ \lambda x}{y}=\frac{\lambda y}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

You've all been very helpful.

So taking it from there:

$x^2 = 2y^2$

$\frac{x^2}{2} = y^2$

**$y = \pm \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$**

Then, replacing in the third equation:

$x^2 + (\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2 = 1$

$x^2 + \frac{x^2}{2} = 1$

$x^2 = \frac{2}{3}$

$x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \Rightarrow y = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

In both points $f$ equals to $\sin(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}) > 0$

Then, looking at the ellipse:

- $x=0 \Rightarrow  y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
- $y=0 \Rightarrow  x = 1$

And $f(x,0) = f(0,y) = 0$, so $f$ has global minima at $(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and $(1,0)$; and global maxima at $(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$ and $(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$.